# how to export init_mm in linux kernel

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel

in my kernel module, I want to use the function [`pgd_offset_k()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/include/asm/pgtable.h?v=3.4;a=arm#L163)

But the function uses `init_mm`, which is not exported for module to use. I find its definition [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/init-mm.c?v=3.4;a=arm#L16)

and tried to add

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL(init_mm);
```

to the end of the file. But the kernel does not compile and gives error about

> mm/init-mm.c:26:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]

what does that mean and how can I use `init_mm` in my module?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
```

Because EXPORT_SYMBOL() macro is defined there.

Comment: Actually, it defined in `#include <linux/export.h>`